# how can you specify the length of an hatccess rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

If I'm doing a rewrite, is there a way to distinguish between the string length, like if it's 2 characters, it goes to one page, but if it's 3 or more, it goes to another one?

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ two-characters.php?u=$1 [QSA] // 2 char
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ three_plus_characters.php?u=$1 [QSA,L] // 3+ char
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try your rule this way.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]{2})/?$ two-characters.php?u=$1 [QSA] // 2 char
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]{3,})/?$ three_plus_characters.php?u=$1 [QSA,L] // 3+ char
```

Comment: I made a quick edit on the second rule to account for more than 3 as well.